# Safely add/remove classes for HTML elements from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having difficulty using this "callmenick" project, [Slide Down Menu](http://callmenick.com/post/simple-responsive-navigation-menu)

Specifically, I want to be able to *dynamically* add classes `.dropdown` and `.sub-menu`, using javascript to my existing `<li>` definition, without removing the classes that are hardcoded in the HTML document for that tag.

```
<li class="button_a hvr-underline"> 
   <a href="#" class="button" style="width: 128px;">a</a>
</li>
```

Comment: I do not understand the point of the question. Add the `dropdown` class to the `<li>`. If that is not possible (you do not control the code perhaps), target the `<li>` with a different selector, e.g. `$('li.button_a.hvr-underline').hover(...)`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 1):

You can use [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method from jquery.

```
 $('.hvr-underline').addClass('dropdown');
```

Comment: sorry dude not working 
i try like that and i change with other class but dropdown still not appear

or maybe i put it in wrong way 
i put that code in new <script>......</script> under my js script

maybe this will help 
my hvr css have child css 
and my button_a css just a single css

Comment: @Awid, but he *did* answer your question. Your question was not how to make your code work in general, it was just how to add classes safely. Of course there's more to making your menus work than *just* adding classe You should click the √ by his answer for solving the question you asked so he gets credit for taking the time to help you.